# ampersand (&) in list definition custom form URLs

Tags: xml, url, schema

I want to use **more then 1 query param** for custom list form.
So, this is XML definition:
    
    _layouts/MyPage.aspx?param1=x&param2=y

When custom form is called for new listitem it sending request like this:

_layouts/MyPage.aspx?param1=x&amp;param2=y

My thoughts are, that querystring being encoded before redirecting from standard SP list form to my custom. I tried also CDATA - didn't work.

Comment: for now, I concat all my params into 1, but I hope its not the best you could do: /MyPage.aspx?aggregatorparam=param1-x.param2-y

Answer (score 2):

An ampersand in XML *must* be escaped as `&amp;`, so your software is behaving quite correctly. When the XML is parsed by the recipient, assuming a correct XML parser, it will translate the escaped `&amp;` back to `&`.

Comment: you are right, but I don't want to customize standard SP listform.aspx that works with all site list forms.

Comment: The problem is that the ampersand is being XML encoded for storage by SharePoint, but SharePoint does NOT properly DECODE the `&amp;` back into a an ampersand, instead using the `&amp;` as part of the resulting query string.